# How do I use JQuery AjaxSetup to set "csrf" as a parameter every time I have an XHR request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
        beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
            console.log(xhr);
            // Here, I want to set csrf token to both POST or GET parameters.
        } 
    });
```

If it's GET, append it to the question mark. If it's a post, extend it to the object.

the reason I don't use `data: {}` is because Backbone.js 0.5 overrides the data, and the csrf does not get appended.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the below solution? The parameter should be added by jquery just before the request gets send

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        csrf: 1
    }
})
```

**Edit**
So then have a go with this one

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        switch (settings.type) {
            case "GET": settings.url += "&csrf=1"; break;
            case "POST": settings.data += "&csrf=1"; break;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ok, then have a try with my second solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the backbone sync method as described in [Backbone and Rails Forgery Protection](http://ngauthier.com/2011/02/backbone-and-rails-forgery-protection.html). It's been packaged up on github [here](https://github.com/Maciek416/BackboneRailsAuthTokenAdapter/blob/master/backbonerailsauthtokenadapter.js).